# Searching and replacing arrays in arrays

Tags: php, arrays

My title is a bit confusing. I will try to explain better what I want to do.
I have an array with other arrays:

```
array (size=16)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      'value' => string 'apple.png' (length=9)
      'x' => int 3
      'y' => int 4
      'status' => boolean false
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      'value' => string 'apple.png' (length=9)
      'x' => int 2
      'y' => int 3
      'status' => boolean false
  2 => 
    array (size=4)
      'value' => string 'cake.png' (length=8)
      'x' => int 3
      'y' => int 1
      'status' => boolean false
```

Then I have a form with hidden inputs:

```
'<input type="hidden" value="x:'.$i.';y:'.$j.'" name="coords"/>';
```

When the form is submitted I get the value and extract the coordinates. Then I do a loop.

```
foreach($this->mapBoard as $block)
{
    if($block['x'] == $x && $block['y'] == $y)
    {
        $block['status'] = true;
        return $block;
    }
    else
    {
        continue;
    }
}
```

The main array is called **'mapBoard'**. My question is how when I find the right array element, to change its value of the **status** key. And put it back in **mapBoard**.

Comment: I'm not quite sure about pointers in php, but `foreach($this->mapBoard as &$block)` should work

Comment: @Imperative its always a bad idea to use references in foreach as it can potentially lead to loss of data in the last item in the list by overwriting it.

Comment: @Kalyan Can you please show us some example? Using the reference is proposed also in [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php): "  In order to be able to directly modify array elements within the loop precede $value with &. In that case the value will be assigned by reference. "

Comment: @Stano the reference to &$block (last element) still remains after the for loop. So if at later point if you use variable $block anywhere, you can potentially modify original array,  due to php's non strict scoping, unless it is explicitly destroyed using `unset()`. You can refer the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)'s *Warning* section.

Comment: @Stano You are right about it. I stand corrected. In function context, it works. The usage still requires understanding of corner cases, and can easily lead to bugs, hence my generalisations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
foreach($this->mapBoard as $key => $block)
{
    if($block['x'] == $x && $block['y'] == $y)
    {
        $this->mapBoard[$key]['status'] = true;
        return $block;
    }
    else
    {
        continue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP's foreach by default makes a copy of the array it is iterating on, so we will have to manually stuff data back in when modified.

Here is a simple tweak to your code to do it

```
// For arrays foreach will give us the loop iteration in `i` while using $i => $block
foreach($this->mapBoard as $i=>$block)
{
    if($block['x'] == $x && $block['y'] == $y)
    {
        $block['status'] = true;
        // we know i is the position, so stuff it back in
        $this->mapBoard[$i] = $block;
        return $block;
    }
    else
    {
        continue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return array key in place of `$block['status'] = true;` , after that you update status according to array key.